# Android Studio Profiler stuck loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I'm trying to use profiler but it's stuck like this.
Strangly I'we used it on same device yesterday and it worked just fine.
Android Studio version I'm using is 3.4.1.
Also tried repluging device but nothing changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by restarting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `SDK platforms` and `SDK built tools` solved my problem.
[image]